# Cannot compile - unknown flag "-pdbrpc" in "p2"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile a C++ project in VS 2017. Previously I used VS 2019 but due to it's annoying bugs I moved back to 2017, but now I get and error: unknown flag "-pdbrpc" in "p2". I don't even know what this flag means and I didn't find it in .vcxproj files.

I tried to change my project's config settings to disable optimization, but didn't succeed. Also I searched that error in google but didn't find anything useful. How can I fix this annoying problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had same problem. Disabling Whole Program Optimization fixed it.

Comment: I had the same issue building a VS2017 project which uses a library build with VS2019. Normally VS2017 & VS2019 are binary compatible but this is not the case with `Whole Program Optimization` enabled. So indeed, disabling it in the VS2019 library solved by VS2017 project build issue.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to downgrade some projects you depend upon.

Make sure all of your projects (including static libraries you link with) use the same v141 (VS2017) Platform Toolset. It can be visible in the Solution Explorer as `Project Name (Visual Studio 2017)`.

In my case I had a hidden `project.default.props` that was using `$(DefaultPlatformToolset)`, which started to point to v142 as soon as I installed VS2019.